# How does the Earth's momentum change when I walk?

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws

When I start to walk, conservation of momentum means that I impart a recoil to the Earth. Owing to the fact that the Earth is around 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 times more massive than I, the recoil speed is extremely close to zero- thousands of times less than the measured diameter of a proton per second.

What I would like to understand, is how the recoil propagates. I assume that the impulse given by my foot to the ground must have an effect that is initially localised and spreads at the speed of sound. I assume that initially there is a distortion of the ground which then relaxes as a progressively greater fraction of the Earth's mass becomes effected by, and absorbs, the impulse. How would you estimate the maximum horizontal displacement of the ground as I start to walk?

Answer (score 3):

> How would you estimate the maximum horizontal displacement of the ground as I start to walk?

I happened to [solve this](http://john.maloney.org/Papers/Influence%20of%20finite%20thickness%20and%20stiffness.pdf) in the context of biological cells pulling laterally on very compliant substrata. I integrated [Green's tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) for a finite area of traction atop a semi-infinite medium or half space. (This is also called the [Boussinesq problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Valentin_Boussinesq).)

If we idealize your foot as a circular area of uniform traction with radius $a$, the effective spring constant of the ground is (Eq. 9)

$$k_\mathrm{eff}=\frac{2\pi\mu a}{2-\nu},$$

where $\mu$ is the shear modulus of the soil and $\nu$ is its Poisson ratio. Taking sample values of $a=5\,\mathrm{cm}$, $\mu= 50\,\mathrm{MPa}$, and $\nu=0.3$, this model predicts a lateral surface displacement of 50 nm for each newton of lateral force arising from friction as you walk forward.

(Even without the exact calculation, you can use scaling arguments to predict $k_\mathrm{eff}\sim \mu a$. Try using this to predict the downward deflection from your weight.)

Comment: Congratulations for spotting the analogy! Not having the stomach for tensors and integration, I made an estimate through simple mental arithmetic which sits very well with yours. I will try to get time to post it today. Cheers!

Comment: I agree that exact analytical answers aren’t essential here and take a lot of time to develop and review. A simple dimensional argument: if you multiply an elastic modulus of the ground by the characteristic length of an effective area, you get a spring constant. Take the reciprocal of that and multiply by a force and you get a displacement.